# .Net 6 WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost.CaptureStartupErrors not working

Tags: .net-6.0, startup

I'm trying to migrate from Startup model to the minimal .NET 6 WebApplication method of running a web application, and I'm specifically interested in keeping the CaptureStartupErrors functionality working.

I am calling the following line on my WebApplicationBuilder, but it makes no difference:
`webApplicationBuilder.WebHost.CaptureStartupErrors(true);`

Since the code is now simply all laid out flat in the Program.cs' Main method, I actually don't know how this would actually work. If I throw an exception there, it will just exist the program.  Am I missing something?